# Load a certain number of file rather scan and load all files in a Directory

Tags: c#, vb.net, file, directory

In vb.net or C#, is it possible to retrieve a certain number of files e.g. 100 from a folder instead of scanning all files (e.g. 1000000) and retrieve them all?

If yes, then what is the implementation?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

In .Net Framework 4.0 and above, you can use [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413232.aspx) and take as many files as you want.  This method does not require a full scan of the directory before it returns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so do it mean there is no way to achieve below .Net 4.0?

Comment: I don't believe there's a means of doing this in the earlier frameworks.

Comment: Thx, do you agree "the FindFirstFile and FindNextFile functions of WinAPI" can achieve the aim?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want a solution that works with versions of .NET Framework prior to version 4, the only thing that comes in mind is the [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions of WinAPI.

Have a look at this implementation of [`EnumerateFiles`](http://www.bratched.com/fr/index/dotnet/52-playing-with-findfirstfile-and-findnextfile.html) based on these WinAPI functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo("c:/mydirectory").EnumerateFiles())
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should first call [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss.aspx) methods to retrieve path of all files related to the directory (files did not read yet) and then read first 100 files (e.g., using StreamReader etc) from the collection.

This will work if framework is below 4.